# How to sort an array in ascending order which has comma delimited strings

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

How do you actually sort this array from the lowest to highest so the outcome would be:

-10,true
-2,true
-1,false
1,true
2,true
10,true

```
String[] arr = new String[6];
arr[0] = "2,true";
arr[1] = "10,true";
arr[2] = "1,true";
arr[3] = "-2,true";
arr[4] = "-10,true";
arr[5] = "-1,false";
```

I have tried with this approach. I know this approach to be fast as it divides minus och plus in to two arrays. But I am not sure how to complete this code exactly?

```
public String[] sortLIST(String[] minusLIST, String[] plusLIST)
    {
        var result = new String[minusLIST.Length + plusLIST.Length];

        var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => plusLIST.AsParallel().OrderByDescending(i => double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0])));
        var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => minusLIST.AsParallel().OrderBy(i => double.Parse(i.Split(',')[0].TrimStart('-'))));
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);



        result.AddRange(t1.Result);
        result.AddRange(t2.Result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: using `System.Linq;` and var sortedArray = arr.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[0])).ToArray();

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please respect the time of the volunteers who answer questions on Stack Overflow and try to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Oguz, thank you your solution worked out. I did EDIT my post with an approach that I have used before that was simular to yours. But I couldn't understand how to complete the code I had exactly so all the sorted lists is added to: `result`?

Comment: @Heretic Monkey. Yes I have, I did edit my post with the approach I really can't understand how to change so it will work.

Comment: Change the first line in method to 
var result = new List<string>();

Comment: @Anton. Yes that could proabably work because `.AddRange` is a property to `List<String>` but I think I am trying to do it with arrays all the way if that is possible. I am not sure how to put `t1.Result` and `t2.Result` to an array?

Comment: Arrays are immutable in C#, so you can't add elements to it once it's created. What you can do is to use Array.Copy method to copy items from t1.Result and then from t2.Result to the result array

Comment: Yes that is true, the thing is that this doesn't work either. I tried that before. The `t1.CopyTo` property doesn't exist there. It says it can't convert: `Task<String[]> to String[]`

Comment: Try t1.Result.CopyTo(result, 0); t2.Result.CopyTo(result, t1.Result.Length)

Comment: @Anton you are the best. That did work! It actually did work with all my code now there with the `minusLIST` and `plustLIST`. The code is very fast also as I have benhmarked it with other sorting methods using `Lists` so it can perheps be of interest. Thank you!

Comment: @Andreas, by the way, if you are interested in fast multi-threaded sorting of such composed strings, it would be good to pay attention also to string comparisons, like I've implemented here https://github.com/anton-danylov/Experiments/tree/master/LargeFileSorter